# Rails Can't verify CSRF token authenticity on Heroku/production only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma, csrf-protection

The app works OK locally in both development and production mode, but once deployed on Heroku, the CSRF validation fails. This is a vanilla, non-ajax request.

Locally, I run in producion mode with

```
RAILS_ENV=production heroku local -e production
```

I wanted to make sure that this is the real issue so I disabled the authenticity token verification and the Heroku version worked, too.

Update: Here's my config:

```
# session_store.rb:
Hlresponse::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_hlresponse_session', domain: :all

# Environment:

$ heroku config:set MIN_THREADS=1 MAX_THREADS=1

# Procfile:

web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb

# config.ru:

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run Rails.application

# puma.rb:

workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

Here are two sets of logs, one without the error (and verification disabled), and another with the verification enabled, with error. Any idea on how to approach this?

With verify_authenticity_token disabled (skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token)

```
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents app/web.1:  Started POST "/admin/snippets" for 64.69.46.217 at 2015-06-06 06:46:57 +0000 
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents heroku/router:  at=info method=POST path="/admin/snippets" host=hlevents.herokuapp.com request_id=5de24f22-13bb-43ff-a8f1-d65efd08b879 fwd="64.69.46.217" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=15ms status=302 bytes=1047 
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents app/web.1:  Processing by SnippetsController#create as HTML 
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents app/web.1:  Processing by SnippetsController#index as HTML 
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents app/web.1:    Rendered shared/admin/_include_bootstrap.html.erb (0.1ms) 
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents app/web.1:    Rendered shared/admin/_breadcrumbs.html.erb (0.2ms) 
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents app/web.1:    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oPdNjND12fwYrx8YdxhdQLqs67JbX8MkNxyGGj8NS2DwxHxe5HK2Fl+FdOSEs4t73ISoGPgF24YeZphwOmsNGg==", "snippet"=>{"name"=>"test2", "draft_content"=>"test2"}, "save_as_draft"=>"true", "commit"=>"Create Snippet"} 
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents app/web.1:  Redirected to https://hlevents.herokuapp.com/admin/snippets 
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents app/web.1:  Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms) 
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents app/web.1:  Started GET "/admin/snippets" for 64.69.46.217 at 2015-06-06 06:46:58 +0000 
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents app/web.1:    Rendered snippets/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.9ms) 
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents app/web.1:    Rendered shared/admin/_menu.html.erb (0.4ms) 
Jun 05 23:46:58 hlevents app/web.1:  Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 5.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

With verify_authenticity_token enabled:

```
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:  Started POST "/admin/snippets" for 64.69.46.217 at 2015-06-06 06:49:38 +0000 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:  Processing by SnippetsController#create as HTML 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:  Can't verify CSRF token authenticity 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:  ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken): 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:181:in `handle_unverified_request' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:209:in `handle_unverified_request' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:204:in `verify_authenticity_token' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:432:in `block in make_lambda' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:164:in `block in halting' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_process_action_callbacks' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"g0mFZ2tEDMvvSiq3FeIUPFTWiwi8N4LO4cs81PkohjoesgtJgGnQ6I7x+L4kwgMFoqHQHYfqQeznMQduOBzgmQ==", "snippet"=>{"name"=>"test3", "draft_content"=>"test3"}, "save_as_draft"=>"true", "commit"=>"Create Snippet"} 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:  Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms) 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/configuration.rb:51:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/server.rb:507:in `handle_request' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/server.rb:375:in `process_client' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/server.rb:262:in `block in run' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `call' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents app/web.1:    vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.3/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:104:in `block in spawn_thread' 
Jun 05 23:49:38 hlevents heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=hlevents.herokuapp.com request_id=c0616b75-9fb0-4ee0-990d-52f2a34333f2 fwd="64.69.46.217" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200
```

Comment: Have you override devise html?

Comment: I am not using devise. There's no authentication yet.

Comment: Can you update your `snippets` form in question ?

Comment: No. Nothing that requires csrf validation works in production.

Comment: You might not using rails form tag thats why no authenticity field generating in your form. That's why I asked you to update your form view. Please verify you are using rails form_tag or html form tag

Comment: Yes, I am using form_for. How do I verify if the correct authenticity tag is used?

Comment: If your html is generating fine then there must be some html similar to this :  `<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"><input type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" name="authenticity_token"></div>` Present in your form. This automatically generating in form tag.

Comment: can you please post your config/initializers/session_store.rb file

Comment: @AmitSharma added my configuration

Comment: where is your sessing_store config

Comment: @AmitSharma, I added this setting to the question (in cookies).

Comment: @Dipak, I tried again and verified that Update actually worked. Also, I notice that the _hlresponse cookie is not visible on Heroku. So, this is a cookie-related issue! Locally, I get the same error if I remove the cookie before posting an edit.

Comment: OK, the issue seems to be in the `domain: :all` in the `config.session_store` statement. I removed this and now cookies function on Heroku, too. I will need multi-domain cookies for this app, though, but I'll look into this again after setting up my custom domain and subdomains for the app.

Comment: remove `domain: :all` and try to run the code.

Comment: Thank you, Amit, I already did as I pointed out in the comment above yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with `domain: :all` in the `:cookie_store` config.

```
Hlresponse::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_hlresponse_session', domain: :all
```

I removed it and the cookies reappeared.

```
Hlresponse::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_hlresponse_session'
```

I will, however, need to have this setting on as I will be using multiple subdomains. I will wait until I set up the custom domain on Heroku and see if it works again. I am wondering if Heroku makes an effort to disable multi-subdomain cookies on their herokuapp.com domain...

Comment: to disable multi-subdomain cookies on herokuapp.com makes perfect sense! And to be honest, you don't want that. That would mean that _any_ app (and that will be 10s of k if not more) can read your cookies. Get your own domain (simple .com  is $12/year with Google), configure that to work with Heroku at no additional costs (even the free dynos allow custom domains)

Comment: Thank you, that's the plan. I'll add the domain and desired subdomains, and if the `domain: :all` works with that set up, I'll accept my own answer :)